Terraform : In firehose streams with s3 as the destination, not able to find New line delimiter enabling option
Terraform : In the firehose stream with S3 as the destination, what is the terraform equivalent parameter for enabling "New line delimiter". FYI, There is no dynamic partition, no lambda. The firehose gets the data from kinesis stream which is configured to dynamodb. 
Please help.
